# How to show charts using Amazon Echo show skill

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

I´ve gotten an echo show on Christmas. Now I want to try out how I can customize it a bit. I have created several sensors whose metrics are stored in an AWS DynamoDB. Now I am wondering what possibilities I have to show charts created out of that data. Is it possible to display charts using Alexa Presentation Language (APL) directly? Is it possible to include iframes in APL?
I did not find much information on that topic. Maybe you can point me to the right direction.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Ok, on the meantime I came across a thread which tells how to use the openURL command to navigate to a website using APL. This is a possible way to display the measured metrics. The question regarding generating charts directly is still open though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, I will show the code a a nodejs function which is able to navigate to an URL:

```
const MetricsChoiceIntentHandler = {
canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'MetricsChoiceIntent';
},
handle(handlerInput) {
    const choice = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.choice.value;
    const speakOutput = `Alles klar. Auf zu ${choice}`;
    console.log("Deine Wahl: "+choice);
    
    if (Alexa.getSupportedInterfaces(handlerInput.requestEnvelope)['Alexa.Presentation.APL']) {
        handlerInput.responseBuilder.addDirective({
            type: 'Alexa.Presentation.APL.RenderDocument',
            document: launchDocument,
            token: 'jip'
        });
        
        var urlToGo="";
        switch(choice){
            case "gaswarner":
                urlToGo="https://www.url1.com";
                break;
            case "temperatur":
                urlToGo="https://www.url2.com"
                break;
        }
        
        handlerInput.responseBuilder.addDirective({
            type: "Alexa.Presentation.APL.ExecuteCommands",
            token: 'jip',
            commands: [{
              type: "OpenURL",
              source: urlToGo
            }]
        });
    }  

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak(speakOutput)
        .getResponse();
}
};
```

There are two important things to mention:

1. You have to respond with a document in order to navigate to a URL. This can also be a blank dummy APL document
2. If you want to navigate to an URL, you have to set the token (which can be anything you like) on both the document and the command directive.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you were looking for, but you can generate SVG graphics and render those using [APL VectorGraphic primitives](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-presentation-language/apl-vectorgraphic.html).

You will have to build a [custom skill](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/understanding-custom-skills.html) that, when invoked, can pull the data for your metrics, and generate the APL to render the graphs.

Alternatively, if you have a different server-side rendering API for the metrics that can rasterize, you can produce a PNG and render that on the Echo Show.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is not as "interactive" as I wanted it to be, but it will definitely work.